# DotNetZip / Bug report

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I probably found a bug with 1.13.6 Version of DotNetZip using c#. 
How can I report this issue, since I cannot find a project site with contacts?

Comment: Take a look at => https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd

Answer (score 0):

Go here: https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd/issues and click the 'New Issue' button.  Sign up for GitHub if you haven't, and then detail your issue.